# Iterate an array using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to loop through an array. My array is as follows:

```
 reasonSaved=  [Type[Id=51327, code=TEE, text=Testing, updatedBy=PRO, updatedId=2345, updatedDate=2021-01-07 07:56:35.0]]
```

And I am using following code:

```
 var reasonSaved= "${master.Type}"; // my array
  $.each(reasonSaved, function(key, value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

I am getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '154' in"

I tried with the below code as well, but it is not displaying as I want

```
for (var i = 0; i < reasonSaved.length; i++) {
    reasonSaved[i];
    console.log(reasonSaved[i]);
}
```

Am trying to get all the data out of the array. Can some one lead me in the right path please?

Comment: that is not a valid array format , you can loop it using js , from where you get this last ?

Comment: This is output of a JSTL array

Comment: Hi, `Type` is class ?